# Android: Sorting a list of objects by one of three string arrays

Tags: android, eclipse, sorting

Okay. So I'm making a little eBook store app. I have a string-array in strings.xml containing a list of books. Each array item contains four pieces of data, including the path to its cover image, the title, author, and genres. In the code below, I create a View object for each book in the array and print them out on-screen. I'm currently using a Tabs+Swipe layout, and there are three tabs: Title, Author, and Genre. What I want to do is sort the array of Views by, you know, either Title, Author, or Genre, depending on which tab is selected. Anyone know of any way that I can do this?

```
public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {
    private static ScrollView outerLayout;
    private static LinearLayout innerLayout;
    private static LayoutParams params;
    private static ArrayList <String []> bookData = new ArrayList <String []> ();
    private static String [] bookList;

    public SectionFragment () { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        params = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        outerLayout = new ScrollView (context);
        outerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        innerLayout = new LinearLayout (context);
        innerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        bookList = res.getStringArray(R.array.bookList);

        for (int i = 0; i < bookList.length; i++) {
            View bookView = new View (context);
            bookView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);

            ImageView bookCover = (ImageView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookCover);
            TextView bookTitle = (TextView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
            TextView bookAuthor = (TextView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
            TextView bookGenre = (TextView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookGenre);

            bookData.add(bookList[i].split("\\|"));
            try {
                bookCover.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(
                        context.getAssets().open(bookData.get(i)[0]), null));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bookTitle.setText(bookData.get(i)[1]); 
            bookAuthor.setText("by " + bookData.get(i)[2]);
            bookGenre.setText(bookData.get(i)[3]);

            innerLayout.addView(bookView);
        }

        outerLayout.addView(innerLayout);
        return outerLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've written for each of the Tab Views? That's where you will have to do the sorting really. You should try creating a static variable in the form of a list of books (which would be similar to bookData or maybe you can use bookData itself). You then have to access this globally available list to sort your books based on the elements of this list, and this you would have to do in your respective TabView

Comment: There really isn't much of anything else. The rest is what was already there when I started the project. I see there is a particular method that changes the data per tab:
`public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {       @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new SectionFragment();
           // Bundle args = new Bundle();
           // args.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
           // fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }`
But I have nothing else there.

Comment: I've changed it so that the bookView objects are added to an ArrayList, similar to bookData. Now obviously I need to sort that array by one of those three attributes before adding them to the screen.

Comment: How/where are you defining the names/headings of the tabs? i.e where are you creating each of the fragments for each of the three tabs: Title, Author, Genre?

Comment: Right now, all three tabs are using the SectionFragment class in my original post. As far as I know, the only way to change it for each tab is through the SectionsPagerAdapter class above. There is also:
`@Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section_1).toUpperCase();
                case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section_2).toUpperCase();
                case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section_3).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }`

Comment: Gimme some time I'll post the code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would advise you to create a Book class that encapsulates imageFilename, title, author and genre (this makes sorting MUCH easier).

```
public class Book{
private String imageName;
private String title;
private String author;
private String genre;

public Book(String image, String title1, String author1, String genre1)
{
  imageName = image;
  title = title1;
  author = author1;
  genre = genre1;
}
public String getImageName()
{
 return this.imageName;
}
public String getTitle()
{
 return this.title;
}
public String getAuthor()
{
return this.author;
}
public String getGenre()
{
 return this.genre;
}
}
```

And then use the following code in your SectionFragment class. This should work as far as I can think. The sorting logic etc. is correct as far as I can think. The only problem that might arise is probably due to the arguments in the switch statement ( getArguments.getInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) 
Oh! also, when you posted the code for getItem(i) you posted this:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{ 
@Override 
public Fragment getItem(int i) { 
Fragment fragment = new SectionFragment(); 
// Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
// args.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1); 
// fragment.setArguments(args); 
return fragment; 
}
```

Make sure you uncomment the last three lines because these are important in the following switch statement in the code I've provided below (to figure out which fragment we are dealing with.)

```
public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {
private static ScrollView outerLayout;
private static LinearLayout innerLayout;
private static LayoutParams params;
private static ArrayList <String []> bookData = new ArrayList <String []> ();
private static String [] bookList;
private static ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

public SectionFragment () { }

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    params = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    outerLayout = new ScrollView (context);
    outerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    innerLayout = new LinearLayout (context);
    innerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    bookList = res.getStringArray(R.array.bookList);
    for(int i = 0; i < bookList.length; i++)
    {
     String filename = bookList[i].split("\\|")[0];
     String title = bookList[i].split("\\|")[1];
     String author = bookList[i].split("\\|")[2];
     String genre = bookList[i].split("\\|")[3];
     Book book = new Book(filename, title, author, genre);
     bookList.add(book);
    }

    switch(getArguments.getInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
    {
    // I am assuming the first fragment is Title
    case(1): Collections.sort(bookList, new Comparator<Book> {
    public int compare(Book a, Book b)
    {
     return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
    }
    });
    break;

    case(2): Collections.sort(bookList, new Comparator<Book> {
    public int compare(Book a, Book b)
    {
     return a.getAuthor().compareTo(b.getAuthor());
    }
    });
    break;

    case(3): Collections.sort(bookList, new Comparator<Book> {
    public int compare(Book a, Book b)
    {
     return a.getGenre().compareTo(b.getGenre());
    }
    });
    break;
    }       

    for (int i = 0; i < bookList.length; i++) {
        View bookView = new View (context);
        bookView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);

        ImageView bookCover = (ImageView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookCover);
        TextView bookTitle = (TextView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
        TextView bookAuthor = (TextView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
        TextView bookGenre = (TextView) bookView.findViewById(R.id.bookGenre);

        try {
            bookCover.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(
                    context.getAssets().open(bookList.get(i).getImageName()), null));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bookTitle.setText(bookList.get(i).getTitle()); 
        bookAuthor.setText("by " + bookList.get(i).getAuthor());
        bookGenre.setText(bookList.get(i).getGenre());

        innerLayout.addView(bookView);
    }

    outerLayout.addView(innerLayout);
    return outerLayout;
}
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Remember the Comparator class as it's extremely helpful in sorting multiple arrayLists simultaneously, although you will have to use encapsulation and create a wrapper class for it to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

bookList contains the whole data so just create your sorting method based on criteria if author selected re-arrange your booklist array based on author name.

Comment: Yes, that would be my goal... and I could achieve it by doing... ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to modify your String arrays programmatically in runtime. Get your full array with `bookList = res.getStringArray(R.array.bookList);`
2. Perform simple string operations and split your strings up to 3 arrays, one for title, Author and Genre and you can sort them alphabetically using Arrays.sort().
   Of course, you will need to use a loop and some programming logic here so when you sort by Title, eg: bookTitleByTitle[0] must correspond to bookAuthorByTitle[0] and bookGenreByTitle[0]. And by the way, Using Arrays.sort() will destroy your original Array, so make copies of your array. (NOT CLONE!).
3. Repeat it for by author and genre.

This would be my approach.